# Testing WPF applications

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, testing

I am currently doing my write-up for my third year degree project. I created a system using C# which used a Microsoft Access as the back end database. The system does not connect to the internet, nor does it use the local network for any connectivity.

I am asking for the best method to test an application such as this, so that it is of sufficient testing.

Comment: When you say testing - what are you looking for? Ensure it has no bugs?  Test a certain percentage of the code?  Honestly your tests should be written as you go.  I am not a fan of TDD - but I am a fan of writing the tests as you write the features.  If your application is complete - it is really too late to "test" it as it should be tested.

Comment: Each item has been tested as I went along, but they weren't documented. I test all my features for as many eventualities as I can think of. But its come to document these now. I am testing the application is free of bugs and that features have been implmented correctly and are working (more or less the same thing)

Comment: When you say tested - do you mean manual testing in the UI, debugging, writing unit tests, integration tests, etc?

Answer (score 2):

You should impelement the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), which will abstract the database code so that you can test the business logic, while faking out the database calls.

Comment: Not sure he is up to the level (for mocking) since he is only in his third year.  Mocking can prove difficult for the more experience developers - much less a student.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you're looking for and how loosely coupled your application is, but in my case, most of the code (roughly 90%) is written so that it can be tested in unit tests, without any need to run the ui. The MVVM pattern is a good starter for that, since it forces you to move code out of your UI into separate classes like ViewModels, Commands, which can be unit tested.

That assures a lot already, and if you need to do automated UI testing, take a look at the Coded UI Tests available in Visual Studio 2010 (Premium and Ultimate only). They allow you to fully automate / simulate user interaction. In simulation, you can do what Justin proposed : detach your application from the database and work with a repository.

You have to keep in mind that in order to write really testable code, you have to design your code testable. In my experience it is next to impossible to write Unit Tests for code written without testing intent right from the start. The probably best thing you can do in that case is write integration tests.

But in order to give more clear advice, we need more input.
Cheers